# Smoothly link the scroll of independent scrollable zones using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, scroll, cross-browser

Configuration is as follows :

_ four independent zones, top_left, left, top_right and right.

_ the scroll should be linked horizontally for a top and its area below

_ the scroll should be linked vertically for each zone and its sibling (on an horizontal axis)

This configuration is described in the picture linked below. Same color means synchronized scroll. A zone to be synchronized with is referred as "scroll-buddy" for the remaining of this question.

[image: Scroll configuration]

I have tried several methods, all of which focuses on user experience using platform-browser-native scroll solutions. In this situation, frameworks like iScroll should be considered as a last resort.

The most obvious solution is to set the scrollTop/scrollLeft of the appropriate scroll-buddy whenever onScroll is called. This is expensive as reading scrollTop/scrollLeft forces the browser to layout. However, performances can be greatly improved by calling requestionAnimationFrame() on this operation. The biggest limitation is probably due to the different ways a browser has to handle scroll events. The result is sparse, at best, with a laggy/"always trying to catch up" synchronization on mobile devices (chrome/safari) due to the specific implementation of inertial scroll.

I have also tried to intercept, clone and redispatch user events to the appropriate scroll-buddy. I am unsuccessful at this point, plus the inertial scrolling is a floating point operation, which results could be very sligthly different even when triggered by the same user event. This could cause a little delta between two scrolling buddies and could be very well perceived on very large scroll zones. A periodic sync is always possible but at this point I simply could not make it work.

I have also considered putting everything in the same scrollable zone but the complexity of this solution is quite remarkable.

My question therefore is very simple : could anybody come up with a better strategy for this problem ? Or simply provide me with an implementation of the first solution that could do the trick, maybe by using something I missed.